# Explanation on lapply subsetting

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me how this lapply works? (It gives a warning but works correctly)

```
A<-matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
B<-matrix(1:16, nrow = 4)
C<-matrix(1:8, nrow = 4)
my.list<-list(A=A, B=B, C=C)
my.list
lapply(my.list, "[",,2)
```

I get the message 'missing argument to function call'

Comment: What warning are you getting?

Comment: "Missing argument to function call"

Comment: What version of R are you running?

Comment: Have you started a new session of R to see if you still get this? I cannot reproduce your error/warning. Provide output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: shorthand for `lapply(my.list, function(x) x[, 2])` which is short for `lapply(my.list, function(x) \`[\`(x, , 2))`

Comment: @Dason version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)

Comment: It shouldn't be about the version of R, I still have 3.0.2 on my disk and it throws no error (Windows 7). Nor with R 3.4.1.

Comment: @rawr Why does the stand-alone `'['(my.list[[1]], , 2)` not work?

Comment: @ChiPak that does work for me, for the first element, I get a vector with length 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after the second argument to `lapply` is passed as an argument to the function.

`` `[` `` is the function you're applying, i.e., you're doing extraction
-  is nothing, so you're sending a missing first argument (in R, this means "all rows")
- `2` is the second argument, which means "second column"

So, to each element `x` of your list, you're applying `x[ , 2]`.

To be honest, the more explicit version is much more readable:

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) x[ , 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Didn't know "[" was a function. Initially I thought it was making some kind of concatenation with the selector x[ , 2].

Comment: @dathanasa everything in R is a function! See Hadley's chapter: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html